# How to create an API Management service programmatically?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I am trying to programmatically (via Azure Resource Manager, if possible) create an APIM service in a specific resource group. The goal is that we can have a template or script that is parameterized and can be checked into source control, so that we can duplicate and recreate our environments.

[This table](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/#web-amp-mobile) in an ARM documentation page says **Yes**, Resource Manager is Enabled for APIM, but the [Quickstart Templates link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Microsoft.ApiManagement%22&type=Code) finds no sample templates for the Microsoft.ApiManagement resource type. However, this could mean merely that no one has yet contributed a template to the gallery, and that I would have to write my own.

As for writing my own ARM template, the [article that walks you through authoring a Resource Manager template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/#resources) says:

> To learn much of what you need to know about resource providers, see [Resource Manager providers, regions, API versions and schemas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/)

... which links back to the same page as my "This table" text above. The same section of the "authoring templates" article also says:

> [Properties are] Resource specific configuration settings. The values for the properties are exactly the same as the values you provide in the request body for the REST API operation (PUT method) to create the resource. For links to resource schema documentation or REST API, see [Resource Manager providers, regions, API versions and schemas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/).

... which again links back to the same page as above.

I have checked both the [APIM REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn776326.aspx) and the [azure-resource-manager-schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas) page for documentation on how to create an APIM instance.

- The APIM REST API requires that you have created an APIM instance already. It's designed for manipulating APIM resources within an APIM instance, not for creating the APIM instance in the first place.
- The ARM schemas project does not contain a schema for Microsoft.ApiManagement. The strings "api management" and "apim" do not occur within the schemas project.

Is it possible to create an API Management service programmatically, and if so, how?

Comment: I think I know where you're going, and you will be annoyed by the fact that you can't (yet) programmatically enable the REST API access to the newly created APIm instance. You also will not be able to update the non-API parts (i.e. the CMS bits) from the outside.

Comment: In parts I take that back; it seems as if the PowerShell Cmdlets actually let you interact with the instance without activating the REST interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create an ApiManagement service programmatically using the Azure Powershell 1.0 commandlets https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/. Below is the commandlet that will help you achieve it.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-help New-AzureRmApiManagement -example

NAME
New-AzureRmApiManagement

SYNOPSIS
Creates an API Management deployment.

SYNTAX
New-AzureRmApiManagement [-Capacity [<Int32>]] [-Sku [<PsApiManagementSku>]] [-Tags [<0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>]] -AdminEmail <String> -Location {North Central US | South Central US | Central
US | West Europe | North Europe | West US | East US | East US 2 | Japan East | Japan West | Brazil South |
Southeast Asia | East Asia | Australia East | Australia Southeast} -Name <String> -Organization <String>
-ResourceGroupName <String> [<CommonParameters>]

Example 1: Create at Developer tier API Management service

PS C:\>New-AzureRmApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "ContosoGroup02" -Name "ContosoApi" -Location "Central US"
-Organization "Contoso" -AdminEmail "admin@contoso.com"


This command creates a Developer tier API Management service. The command specifies the organization and the
administrator address. The command does not specify the SKU parameter. Therefore, the cmdlet uses the default
value of Developer.


Example 2: Create a Standard tier service that has three units

PS C:\>New-AzureRmApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "ContosoGroup02 -Name "ContosoApi" -Location "Central US"
-Organization "Contoso" -AdminEmail "admin@contoso.com" -Sku Standard -Capacity 3


This command creates a Standard tier API Management service that has three units.
```

You can find additional commandlets by using

```
 get-Help AzureRmApiManagement
```

Full documentation of the commandlets can be found here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619282.aspx

Comment: This works for now. Upvoted and will accept if no one comes in with a solution that uses RM templates within the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [quickstart API Management Service ARM template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/f0f5eccd6786d2f2c9a047a1c561900feff57933/101-azure-api-management-create/azuredeploy.json)  from GitHub.

Comment: The ARM template (which we are now using instead of Powershell) merely stands up the APIM instance in the resource group. It doesn't populate the APIM instance with your API, or groups, or products, or policies. For that, you still need the REST API.

Comment: Ah - sorry, I misunderstood your question as only wanting to create the resource, not create and populate.

Comment: No problem, the information about the quickstart template is still helpful for the next person to come along.

Comment: We have release support for ARM templates to manage all entities. [ARM Template to manage all Entities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-api-management-create-all-resources/)

Answer (score 0):

`New-AzureRmApiManagement` can be used to create APIM instance. But provisioning an APIM instance takes time, usually 20 to 30 minutes. If you have to create multiple instances, to save time, it's better to do it with an Azure Automation runbook, and run this command in parallel. [Here](https://blog.himorpheus.com/2018/01/19/create-api-management-instances-in-parallel-with-automation-runbook/) is an example.